# pytest-ing a function with no arguments

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to complete a popular online python course. For the final project, I am required to test functions with pytest.
However, the functions I have are simple, and the inputs are error checked before they are put in the class object `Prime_Line`.
Is there any way to run pytest on a function such as below without re-writing a whole bunch of robust, working, code just so I can run a test on it?

Ex:

```
def extrusion_calculation():
    """Calculates extrusion number

    Returns:
        e (float): extrusion distance
    """
    D = Prime_Line.nozzle_diameter
    W = Prime_Line.line_width_factor * D
    T = Prime_Line.layer_height
    L = Prime_Line.line_length

    e = ((math.pi * T**2) / 4 + T * W - T**2) * L
    return e
```

Comment: Yes, why should you not be able to test this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dummy `Prime_Line` object in a test module using the `Mock` module. In code should be something like that:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock
import math

def test_extrusion_calculation():
    # Create a mock object for Prime_Line
    Prime_Line = Mock()

    # Set the values for the mock object's attributes
    Prime_Line.nozzle_diameter = 0.4
    Prime_Line.line_width_factor = 0.7
    Prime_Line.layer_height = 0.2
    Prime_Line.line_length = 10

    # Call the function and assert the result is what you expect
    assert extrusion_calculation() == 4.76
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work. How does `extrusion_calculation` get a reference to the mocked object?

Comment: I got it to work by passing `Prime_Line` to the function in the assert statement.